# replace functions with a different function in python

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, mocking

I have a function called get_account(param1,param2)
in run time I need to replace this function with the function mock_get_account(param1,param2)
so when the system calls get_account(param1,param2) I need the mock_get_account(param1,param2) to be called instead.

I tried this code:
        package.get_account=self.mock_get_account
        package.get_account(x,y)
but still the get_account runs instead of the mock_get_account
I'm new to python and I don't know if this is even possible but I have seen the lamda function and I know that function programming is possible in python. Thanks
Edit:
if i do the following:

```
package.get_account=self.mock_get_account 
package.get_account(x,y)
```

then every thing is ok, meaning the mock_get_account is called, but in mu code I the following code i do a post self.client.post(url, data=data, follow=True) that triggers the package.get_account and this is not working:

```
package.get_account=self.mock_get_account 
 package.get_account(x,y) 
 #the folowing call will trigger the package.get_account(x,y) function in a django url        #callback
 self.client.post(url, data=data, follow=True)
```

meaning it calls the old function, also get_account(param1,param2) is defined in side a file, and is not a child function of a class and mock_get_account(self,param1,param2) is defined in a class Test and is called inside the Test.test_account - function

Comment: What you have described should work fine. Please give us the actual code and results.

Comment: Can you post up some actual code?  Monkey patching like this is used in a number of distributed packages, so it does work if done correctly.

Comment: if i co the following: package.get_account=self.mock_get_account package.get_account(x,y) and then run package.get_account every thing is ok, in the following code i do a post self.client.post(url, data=data, follow=True) that triggers the package.get_account and this is not working, meaning it prints the old function, also get_account(param1,param2) is defined in side a file, and is not a child function of a class and mock_get_account(self,param1,param2) is defined in a class Test and is called inside the Test.test_account - function

Answer (score 0):

This is very opinionated and does not (directly) answer your question, but hopefully solves your problem.

A better practice is to use a subclass with your `mock_get_account`'s implementation override the parent `get_account` method, example below:

```
class A(object):

    def get_account(self):
        return 1

    def post(self):
        return self.get_account()

class B(A):

    def get_account(self):
        return 2  # your original mock_get_account implementation

a = A()
print(a.get_account())

b = B()
print(b.post())  # this .post will trigger the overridden implementation of get_account
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the code implementing `self.client.post` has access to `get_account` through an import statement that looks like `from package import get_account`.

`from package import get_account` will first load `package` if it hasn't been already imported. Then it will look for a name `get_account` in that module, and whatever object that was bound to will be bound in the importing package's namespace, also under the name `get_account`. Thereafter the two names refer to the same object, but they are not the same name.

So if your mocking code comes along *after* this point, it sets the name `get_account` in `package` to instead refer to `mock_get_account`. But that'll only affect code that reads `get_account` from `package` again; anything that's *already* imported that name specially won't be affected.

If the code behind `self.client.post` instead had access only to `package` through `import package`, and was calling `package.get_account` it would work, because it's then only the object representing the `package` module that has been bound in the importing module's namespace. `package.get_account` would be reading an attribute of that object, and so would get whatever the current value is. If the `from package import get_account` appeared at function local scope rather than module scope, then this would behave similarly.

If I'm correct and your code is structured this way, then it's unfortunately not really `package.get_account` you need to rebind to a mock, but the `get_account` name in the module where `self.client.post` comes from (as well as any other modules which may call it).